# Using tabular environment for text with line break in memoir

Tags: memoir

I would like to have the following result....

[image]

But I noticed that it is not possible to have a linebreak within the tabular environment...and the `\\` command simply makes the compilation crash.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tabular}{c c}
         1 – Valorização da Capacidade de Raciocínio   & 1 – Valorização da Vivência interior             \\
            2 – Funções da Inteligência e Memória      & 2 – Funções da Intuição da Verdade               \\
        3 – Desenvolvimento das   Ciências Matemáticas & 3 – Desenvolvimento das Ciências do Ser Humano   \\
               4 – O Desabrochar da TECNOLOGIA         & 4 – O Desabrochar da SABEDORIA                   \\
           5 – Aperfeiçoamento do Conforto Exterior    & 5 – Aperfeiçoamento do Viver Bem (em paz)        \\
                  6 – Facilidades Exteriores           & 6 – Tranquilidade Interior                       \\
         7 – A Verdade Cartesiana: “Conheça o mundo”   & 7 – A Verdade Socrática: “Conhece-te a ti mesmo”
    \end{tabular}\]
\end{document}
```

I have thought of editing row by row myself....but even so it gets lost in alignment....as you can see in the picture...

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \[\begin{tabular}{c c}
            1 – Valorização da      & 1 – Valorização da Vivência \\
         Capacidade de Raciocínio   & interior                    \\
                                    &  \\
        2 – Funções da Inteligência & 2 – Funções da Intuição da  \\
                 e Memória          & Verdade                     \\
                                    &  \\
          3 – Desenvolvimento das   & 3 – Desenvolvimento das     \\
           Ciências Matemáticas     & Ciências do Ser Humano      \\
                                    &  \\
           4 – O Desabrochar da     & 4 – O Desabrochar da        \\
                TECNOLOGIA          & SABEDORIA                   \\
                                    &  \\
          5 – Aperfeiçoamento do    & 5 – Aperfeiçoamento do      \\
             Conforto Exterior      & Viver Bem (em paz)          \\
                                    &  \\
        6 – Facilidades Exteriores  & 6 – Tranquilidade Interior  \\
                                    &  \\
         7 – A Verdade Cartesiana:  & 7 – A Verdade Socrática:    \\
             “Conheça o mundo”      & “Conhece-te a ti mesmo”
    \end{tabular}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please check whether the following helps:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}<{~}}
\begin{document}
    $$\extrarowheight=6pt
    \begin{tabular}{|C|C|}
    \hline
         1  Valorização da Capacidade de Raciocínio   & 1  Valorização da Vivência interior             \\
            2  Funções da Inteligência e Memória      & 2  Funções da Intuição da Verdade               \\
        3  Desenvolvimento das   Ciências Matemáticas & 3  Desenvolvimento das Ciências do Ser Humano   \\
               4  O Desabrochar da TECNOLOGIA         & 4  O Desabrochar da SABEDORIA                   \\
           5  Aperfeiçoamento do Conforto Exterior    & 5  Aperfeiçoamento do Viver Bem (em paz)        \\
                  6  Facilidades Exteriores           & 6  Tranquilidade Interior                       \\
         7  A Verdade Cartesiana: Conheça o mundo   & 7  A Verdade Socrática: Conhece-te a ti mesmo     \\
         \fbox{TER OBJETOS} & \fbox{SER GENTE}\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    $$
\end{document}
```

I have added a new column specifier `C` with:

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}<{~}}
```

Comment: I do not know what exactly you did, but it worked.
I may have to include extra table in this document...is there a way to do this changes only in this page?...I mean, not to affect all the document and maybe causing trouble.

Comment: Would it be possible to include the "TER OBJETOS" and "SER GENTE" as shown in the pictures? another option I believe is by making it a picture and including it with `\includegraphics`

Comment: I have added: `\extrarowheight=6pt` which is used to increase the skip between adjacent rows; defined a new column specifier `C` with: `\newcolumntype{C}{>{\footnotesize\centering\arraybackslash}p{.45\textwidth}<{~}}`; and two `\hline` just at top and bottom of tabular.

Comment: @Adriano: Will do it now.

Comment: @Adriano: I have added `             \fbox{TER OBJETOS} & \fbox{SER GENTE}\\` to my source. Could you please check it?

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help @Jagath AR 
So I believe that if I do not use the column type `C` there will be no affecting changes or problems throughout the document, am I right?

Comment: @JagathAR What does the {~} do at the end of the \newcolumn specification?

Comment: @acarlow: It just adds a space :-)

Comment: Thanks again for the help.
Worked like a charm.
@JagathAR

Comment: @JagathAR: Please see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)